# Знаки «Диктор», «Усилитель» и «Публицист»

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Прочитав описание знаков, исключительно ради тестирования сайта на дефекты — иначе помалкивал бы, а если б значок присвоили, то планировал сообщить сюда, — набрал просмотры при помощи сервиса захода с различных IP. Не прошло, то есть накрутками знак не получишь, что отлично.

Но какие заходы действительно засчитываются? Ведь если разместишь ссылку, например, на форуме, по ней перейдут за непродолжительный промежуток времени, а затем о ссылке благополучно забудут, — тот же принцип. Не посчитают ли система множество заходов от реальных людей за короткий срок накруткой?

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько условий:

1. [Ссылка должна иметь референтную часть](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274712/2790048) - id пользователя в конце ссылки:

   > meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2895/**181472**
2. Переходы внутри одного сайта не считаются. Исключение - когда пользователь отключает передачу информации об источнике ссылки (referer).
3. Но между сайтами сети SE переходы считаются ([информация от августа 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297923/does-announcer-badge-count-increase-when-link-is-opened-from-inside-stackexchang/297924#comment232462_297924))
4. Посещения одного пользователя с разных IP наверняка не засчитываются.
5. TOR - неизвестно, не нашёл информации.
6. Можно делиться ссылкой на любой вопрос, не только свой.
7. Можно поставить id другого пользователя, чтобы он (возможно) получил знак.

[Узнать информацию об источниках переходов по вашей ссылке невозможно](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299596/2790048) - SE не предоставляет статистику. Если есть необходимость считать количество переходов, то можно завернуть рефссылку в короткую ссылку с помощью любого сервиса коротких ссылок, который позволяет считать это количество.

Comment: Не нашёл ответа именно на поставленный мной вопрос о накрутках. Референтная часть присутствовала, заходы осуществлялись с различных IP — не моих, но значка не получил. // 2 — можно пояснить, как «отключить передачу информации об источнике ссылки»?

Answer (score 2):

Нет никаких ограничений. Если вы сможете вывести на главную Реддита свою референтную ссылку, и по ней пройдут сотни тысяч посетителей, то Stack Overflow будет только рад, поверьте. Серверы мощные, код качественный, система эту нагрузку запросто выдержит.

Получение значков за ссылки действительно не требует больших усилий, просто этим мало кто занимается, поэтому обладателей значков немного. И не преувеличивайте свои способности по завлечению пользователей — получить 1000 переходов не так просто, как вам кажется (у меня только один раз получилось, хотя спамлю референтными ссылками при любом удобном случае).

HTML-фреймами на популярных сайтах значок не заработаешь, но там ограничение на техническом уровне (заголовками HTTP), поэтому вам опасаться нечего.

Кроме того, референтная ссылка — по сути обычная краткая ссылка на пост с вашим идентификатором пользователя в конце. Их можно создать для любого пользователя, не только для себя. Если бы за "неправильное" использование ссылки могли забанить, тогда нашлись бы "доброжелатели", размещающие чужие ссылки. То есть банить за это было бы губительно для сайта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в особенности, за последний абзац. Только где это я «преувеличивал свои способности по завлечению пользователей»?

Comment: @СашаЧерных Когда вы сказали, что по вашей ссылке пройдёт настолько много посетителей, что сайт сочтёт это накруткой. :) Что касается вашего "сервиса захода с различных IP", то недостаточно деталей: работал ли жабоскрипт, сколько было IP и т. п.

Comment: **[1]** Где говорил, что по **моей** ссылке перейдёт настолько множество посетителей? // **[2]** Сервис [этот](https://ping-admin.ru/free_test/), я рандомно выставил 30 галочек (для значка нужно 25). Перед этим проверил работоспособность на сайте, не защищённом от накруток посещений — отобразилось +30 посещений. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Скорее всего, этот сервис делает ровно один запрос — HTML страницы. Подозреваю, что СО может использовать для подсчёта JS. Полноценные спамерские фермы прокси-серверов будут работать, но это удовольствие несколько дороже. :)